# Jenkins execute job only when GIT diff

Tags: git, jenkins

I set up my Jenkins with Bitbucket. In Bitbucket I use a webhook to trigger the Jenkins job on a commit to the repository. The problem now is that any commit to any branch triggers this webhook and so always this job.
On different question I first found the "solution" to set the branch to be build in Jenkins GIT plugin to ***/master**. This though is not really a solution. The job is trigred anyway, but it will only build the master branch. The next steps in my job will be executed anyway.

So I tried another "solution" where I put in the "**Execute shell**" step an if/else to check whether "git diff" is true or false. But this always exited with "**no changes**" so I ended up never executing this shell step. Though the other steps after this were executed.
My conclusion why *git diff* never had some changes is that before I run this command, the GIT plugin already fetched the newest files.

What I'm looking for is that the GIT plugin is looking for the master branch and if there were no changes the whole job is canceled, the status has to stay as it was before.

Is there a configuration I missed? Do you know a workaround to this?